# What is matched filter in QPSK signal?

Tags: filters, digital-communications, matched-filter

Consider we have received a QPSK signal. We than make I (In phase) and Q (quadrature component) which I understand is nothing but multiplying the received signal by the cos(2*pi*f) and -sin(2*pi*f) Where f is the carrier frequency. Is this creation of I and Q is matched filter or there is some other filtering we do which is termed as matched filtering. I will appreciate any clarification?

Edit: Is it that we use some matched filter on I and Q data. What matched filter we use depends on the transmitter characteristic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're not going to send and receive those symbols directly, you know?

What you'll need to convey the information over a channel is a waveform. Your receiver will then typically use the same waveform to correlate the signal. Say you are using [root raised cosine pulses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-raised-cosine_filter) to transmit, then your receiver will employ a root raised cosine filter as a **pulse matched filter** to maximize the SNR.

There may be other things you can matched filter against. For instance, if you have an idea what your channel looks like, you might use a **channel matched filter** to maximize the SNR conveyed over your channel. Or maybe you are using spread spectrum techniques to transmit your information or things like code multiplex? You might want to use a [**code matched filter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter#Matched_filter_in_digital_communications).

So, matched filtering can be used for a lot of things, the term alone doesn't tell it...

Comment: I am not using RRC, for example I am using simple carrier with frequency f and QPSK, in such case I get I and Q and what is the Matched filter in that case. I do not understand the difference between I and Q and matched filter. Assume no channel effect. Is it that we use some matched filter on I and Q data?

Comment: So you are using rectangular pulses? I'm surprised, due to their huge spectral leakage. But yeah I guess in this case integrating against your cos/sin carrier is what you could call matched filter. If your ADCs apply oversampling you can also do some matched filtering in the digital domain, using your I/Q samples. Totally depends on your system parameters.

Comment: Hopefully I am beginning  to understand it. So, If I do RRC as you suggested, than matched filter, which is again RRC would be applied on I and Q signal. Am I correct? Would you please clarify? i would love to accept your answer and upvote.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, the pulse matched filter is something you would typically apply digitally, i.e., based on the I/Q samples. If you sample the result of this filter at its maximum point, you are guaranteed to get the best SNR.